# Since electron clouds of different atoms repel each other, does that mean that touch is the feeling of electromagnetic repulsion?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, atomic-physics

Also when we rest our hand on an object does that mean we are effectively levitating because of the repulsion of the electron clouds?

Answer (score 2):

Yes ... but let's be careful to understand that the sensation of touch is a psychophysical phenomenon.  The electrons at the surface of an object "push" against the electrons at the surface of your fingers.  The electrons never touch each other.  Your skin deforms a bit, and the nerves in your fingers detect this deformation, and send a signal to your brain.  Your brain creates the sensation of touch.

I don't know if I'd use the word "levitate", but it is true that there is a tiny gap between the electrons.